# Problem solving involving time

Tags: problem-solving

You have from 10 pm to 11:30 pm to do a project. At 10:34 what fraction of the project remains?

I keep getting stuck and I don't know why. There is an hour and a half to do the project and at  10:34 I know there are 56 minutes left to complete the project but what is the fraction?

Comment: Well, why not $\frac{56}{90}$ then ?

Comment: The first $90\%$ of a project takes the first $90\%$ of the time. The last $10\%$ of the project takes the other $90\%$ of the time.

Comment: It's `time remaining/time allotted`. So for a 90 minute time box you start with 90/90 (1 x 100 = 100%) and as the time elapses the `time remaining` decreases.

Answer (score 2):

$56\over 90$ of the allotted time remains.

How much of the task remains depends on how fast you work.